# Displaying hex values inside an array to stdout, and comparing input to those hex values

Tags: c, arrays, memcmp

This is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int target;
    char array[] = {'AC', 'EE', '88', '0D', '87'};

    printf("Enter the target byte as a hex value: \n");
    scanf("%x", &target);

    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Value of array[%d] is %x \n", i, array[i]);
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (memcmp(target, array, sizeof(target) == 0))
        {
            printf("Found a match!");
        }
    }
}
```

(1) I want to be able to display to stdout the exact values inside of my char array[]. Things I've tried that do not work: displaying the array as `%c, %x, %d`.
(2) After I get the input from the user, I want to be able to compare that input to the characters inside of the array - figured memcmp would be the way to go, but how do I traverse through the entire array? I tried doing `if (memcmp(target, array[i], sizeof(target) == 0))` but I'd get a runtime error because of the `array[i]` part, but if I don't add that part, how will it go through the entire array comparing the values stored in each array memory location to the value stored in the `target` variable? I basically want to compare bytes inside each array location to the bytes the input by the user.

Comment: Try with `char array[] = {0xAC, 0xEE, 0x88, 0x0D, 0x87};`. And print using `%x`. Other thing your `memcmp` call is wrong. You can just compare `if (target == array[i])`.

Comment: Have you tried to compile it - it does not - see http://cfiddle.net/aLgUal. Here is a good starting point. Get it to compile!

Comment: ..just remove the second `int i = 0` and it compiles just fine, thanks. Anyway, @MuriloVasconcelos, I tried initializing my array to what you said, and now my problem is that those initialized values are being displayed as `ffffffac, ffffffee, ffffff88` etc, so how do I make my comparison ignore the leading `ffffff`?

Comment: It is because it is a signed array. Try this way: `unsigned char array[] = {0xAC, 0xEE, 0x88, 0x0D, 0x87};`.

Comment: I was just about to type that I changed it since I just noticed that, ha. Thank you, though! However, your suggestion of `if (target == array[i])` does not work for some reason, and I tried that earlier too and couldn't get it to work thus why I considered using `memcmp()`. Any suggestions on the comparing part?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution. I uploaded it here:http://codepad.org/pDtqRBSd. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @relapsn You can add your solution as an answer to your own question. Although I'd use sizeof(array) to get the length instead of getting an end point with an explicit +5.

Comment: I'll do that now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should store the hex values in your array as `0xAC` etc, not `'AC'` (which is a multi character constant and not at all what you want).
2. Store your hex values as `unsigned char` because on platforms where `char` defaults to `signed` you're going to get some values (negative ones) being cast to `int` and sign-bit padded accordingly, which is then displayed.
3. Your `memcmp` is call wrong and using it is unnecessary anyway.
4. Your example code won't compile because you have two declarations of `int i` in the same scope. If you aren't using C89 why aren't you writing your for loops as `for(int i = 0;...)` anyway?
5. Don't forget your return value for main.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int target;
  const unsigned char array[] = { 0xAC, 0xEE, 0x88, 0x0D, 0x87 };
  const int len = sizeof array;

  printf("Enter the target byte as a hex value: \n");
  scanf("%x", &target);

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    printf("Value of array[%d] is 0x%x\n", i, array[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  {
    if (target == array[i])
    {
      printf("Found a match!\n");
    }
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I already got my answer before you answered this, but your response brought up something I've been meaning to ask. I'm using Code::Blocks to program in C/C++, and when using C I can't use `for (int i = 0; //etc` because the compiler tells me it's using C89. How do I update my compiler to a more recent one?

Comment: Haha, was just about to say that. What compiler are you using btw? You might want to look into warning and error flags like `-Wall` (for gcc and clang). In fact I strongly recommend you do.

Comment: I'm using the GNU GCC compiler. And those were enabled by default, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This question was part of a bigger program, but it was just this small portion that I couldn't figure out to begin with. In the end, I got everything worked out. Below is the final code of the actual program, and at the bottom are the function definitions I wrote with the help of a couple of users. Again, thank you!

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdint.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>


// defined constants
#define MAX_WIDTH       20
#define NUMELEMS        50


// typedefs and function prototypes
typedef unsigned char   Byte;
void DispBytes(void *voidArray, int totalBytes);
int CountMatchBytes(void *voidArray, int totalBytes, int targetHex);


// ==== main ==================================================================
//
// ============================================================================

int     main(void)
{
    auto    double          myDoubles[NUMELEMS];
    auto    int             myInts[NUMELEMS];
    auto    char            myChars[NUMELEMS];
    auto    int             target;
    auto    int             numMatches;

    // process the char array
    puts("Here's the array of chars as bytes: ");
    DispBytes(myChars, sizeof(myChars));
    printf("\nEnter the target byte as a hex value: ");
    scanf("%x", &target);
    numMatches = CountMatchBytes(myChars, sizeof(myChars), target);
    printf("There %s %d matching byte%s.\n\n", (1 == numMatches ? "is" : "are")
                                             , numMatches
                                             , (1 == numMatches ? "" : "s"));
    // process the int array
    puts("\nHere's the array of ints as bytes: ");
    DispBytes(myInts, sizeof(myInts));
    printf("Enter the target byte as a hex value: ");
    scanf("%x", &target);
    numMatches = CountMatchBytes(myInts, sizeof(myInts), target);
    printf("There %s %d matching byte%s.\n\n", (1 == numMatches ? "is" : "are")
                                             , numMatches
                                             , (1 == numMatches ? "" : "s"));
    // process the double array
    puts("\nHere's the array of doubles as bytes: ");
    DispBytes(myDoubles, sizeof(myDoubles));
    printf("Enter the target byte as a hex value: ");
    scanf("%x", &target);
    numMatches = CountMatchBytes(myDoubles, sizeof(myDoubles), target);
    printf("There %s %d matching byte%s.\n\n", (1 == numMatches ? "is" : "are")
                                             , numMatches
                                             , (1 == numMatches ? "" : "s"));

    return  0;

}  // end of "main"

void DispBytes(void *voidArray, int totalBytes)
{
    // Sets startingPtr to the base address of the passed array
    auto unsigned char *startingPtr = voidArray;
    // Sets endingPtr to one address past the array
    auto unsigned char *endPtr = voidArray + totalBytes;
    auto int counter = 0;

    // Loop while the address of startingPtr is less than endPtr
    while (startingPtr < endPtr)
    {
        // Display the values inside the array
        printf("%x ", *startingPtr);
        counter++;

        if (counter == MAX_WIDTH)
        {
            printf("\n");
            counter = 0;
        }
        // Increment the address of startingPtr so it cycles through
        // every value inside the array
        startingPtr++;
    }
}

int CountMatchBytes(void *voidArray, int totalBytes, int targetHex)
{
    // Sets startingPtr to the base address of the passed array
    auto unsigned char *startingPtr = voidArray;
    // Sets endingPtr to one address past the array
    auto unsigned char *endingPtr = voidArray + totalBytes;
    auto int counter = 0;
    // Loop while the address of startingPtr is less than endPtr
    while (startingPtr < endingPtr)
    {
        // If the input value is the same as the value inside
        // of that particular address inside the array,
        // increment counter
        if (targetHex == *startingPtr)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        // Increment the address of startingPtr so it cycles through
        // every value inside the array
        startingPtr++;
    }
    // Return the number of times the input value was found
    // within the array
    return counter;
}
```